# How I can fix this code? (Android Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin

I made this code for to drawing polygon in googlemaps android. I made from this lib [Map Drawing](https://github.com/bkhezry/MapDrawingTools/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/github/bkhezry/demomapdrawingtools/ui/MainActivity.java).

I made this code with kotlin, i get error. **Here is my code:**

```
...
    private fun getMarkers(points: Array<LatLng>): List<ExtraMarker> {
        val extraMarkers: List<ExtraMarker> = ArrayList()
        @IdRes val icon = R.drawable.ic_add_polypoint
        for (latLng in points)
        {
            val extraMarker = ExtraMarkerBuilder()
                    .setCenter(latLng)
                    .setIcon(icon)
                    .build()
            extraMarkers.add(extraMarker) <--- error in here (add)
        }
        return extraMarkers
    }
```

Error in here

```
extraMarkers.add(extraMarker)
```

I build from this code:

```
private List<ExtraMarker> getMarkers(LatLng[] points) {
        List<ExtraMarker> extraMarkers = new ArrayList<>();
        @IdRes int icon = R.drawable.ic_beenhere_blue_grey_500_24dp;
        for (LatLng latLng : points) {
            ExtraMarker extraMarker =
                    new ExtraMarkerBuilder()
                            .setCenter(latLng)
                            .setIcon(icon)
                            .build();
            extraMarkers.add(extraMarker);
        }
        return extraMarkers;
    }
```

Please help me, how can fix it?
Thank you.

Comment: *`I made this code with kotlin, i get error.`* What ERROR?

Comment: post your stack trace here. It will greatly help to diagnose the problem faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
private fun getMarkers(points: Array<LatLng>): List<ExtraMarker> {
        val extraMarkers: ArrayList<ExtraMarker> = ArrayList()
        @IdRes val icon = R.drawable.ic_add_polypoint
        for (latLng in points)
        {
            val extraMarker = ExtraMarkerBuilder()
                    .setCenter(latLng)
                    .setIcon(icon)
                    .build()
            extraMarkers.add(extraMarker) 
        }
        return extraMarkers
    }
```

Hope this will help.

Some [explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50893555/5275639)

For people just migrating from java, In Kotlin List is by default immutable and mutable version of Lists is called MutableList.

Hence if you have something like :

```
val list: List<String> = ArrayList()
```

In this case you will not get an `add()` method as list is immutable. Hence you will have to declare a MutableList as shown below :

```
val list: MutableList<String> = ArrayList()
```

Now you will see an `add()` method and you can add elements to any list.

Answer (score 0):

For those who just begin the tour of Kotlin, especially come from Java, I suggest you try this site: http://try.kotlinlang.org/

There is a button call `convert from Java`:

[image]

By using this method, you can copy the original Java snippet and easily convert to Kotlin code. For example, I take your original Java code and paste to the dialog then I got this result:

[image]

Easy to use, and it's helpful if you are just start to code in Kotlin.